# Can anyone identify this woody plant

Tags: species-identification

[image][image]They were cut a while ago and have paper like bark, the newer bark is a reddish colour and the old is almost black, the leaves are long and slender and it had some yellow flower buds

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaYM4.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARWuG.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCPum.jpg

Comment: Hello LIam! It would be helpful if you added the location of where you found this plant. Also, I use the iNaturalist app regularly-- and it's auto classifiers are pretty good at helping me identify a plant (immediately), and in my area they are usually followed up by a crowd-sourced (human!) identification within a few days. Plus, these pics can hopefully be used for science! You can add the app to your phone and use in real time. Check it out here: https://www.inaturalist.org/

Comment: This one has been bothering me, I keep coming back to it. I'm sure I've seen the plant as a non-native in the UK, perhaps a botanical garden or the like. Bookmarked in case it comes to mind.

Comment: This one has been bothering me as well! Perhaps a neighbor has it in their yard? I dropped the picture into two different online databases (https://identify.plantnet.org/ and https://plant.id/ and did not get the correct match. If you have a location, that would help!

Comment: Leaves and flowers bring to mind Australian and South African (fynbos) plants. The flower is odd though,

Answer (score 1):

Almost got it, I reckon:

I think that this is one of the *[Hakea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hakea)* species, but it could be another of similar genera, such as [Grevillea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grevillea). Hakea are moderately diverse group of Australian plants in the [Proteaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proteaceae). They are hardy and are like places that reach very high temps in the summer, and I think all need fire to open their seed pods. This group of plants have very distinctive flowers, with the stamens sticking out and curling around (OP's second image).

I think this is probably *[Hakea arborescens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hakea_arborescens)*, as this has yellow flowers and strap-like leaves, whereas most of the other species have white flowers. *H. arborescencs* is also one of the more commonly planted species in those areas where it is used as a garden plant. There's also *[Hakea nodosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hakea_nodosa)* with yellow flowers, but it has stick-like leaves.